# Axios, ChartJS, React, passing state to GraphJS

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, babeljs, axios

I am loading a json from a http request in Axio.
React cannot pass objects into state so I convert them into two arrays.
I want to take the arrays and inject them into

```
myChart = {
        data: {
          labels: getLabels(),
```

and

```
myChart = {
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data: getData(),
```

I am not sure what im suppose to do, is this some type of binding method?

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Component } from "react";
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;


  
class Graph extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mode: undefined } ;
  }
  
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      rates: []
    }
  }

  
  componentDidMount() {
    var jsonLoc = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD";
    axios
    .get(jsonLoc)
    .then(res => {
          var jsonObject = res.data;
          console.log(jsonObject.rates);

          var keyArray = [];
          var valueArray = [];
          var object = jsonObject.rates;
          for (var prop in object){
              keyArray.push(prop);
              valueArray.push(object[prop]);
          }
          
          console.log(keyArray);
          console.log(valueArray);
          this.setState({ label: keyArray })
          this.setState({ data: valueArray })
          
          }
        )
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }
  
  render() {
    
    function getLabels(){
      return [
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday",
      ];
    }
    
    function getData(){
      return [1232, 2321, 15333,4020, 6043, 12313, 5453,  ];
    }
    
    var myChart = {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: getLabels(),
          datasets: [{
            label: "Graph1",
            data: getData(),
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.3)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          }]
        },
        options: {
          "showScale" : true, //grid and scale numbers
          "showTooltips" : true,
          "responsive" : true,
          "maintainAspectRatio" : false,
          "pointDot" : true,
          "bezierCurve" : true,
          "datasetFill" : true,
          "animation" : true,
          "barShowStroke" : false,
          "barStrokeWidth" : 1,
          "barValueSpacing" : 1,
          "barDatasetSpacing" : 1,
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
        }
    };
    
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
        <LineChart ref="chart" data={myChart.data} options={myChart.options} width="600" height="250"/>
        {this.state.label}
        {this.state.data}
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

             
export default Graph;
```

Comment: Why do you say 'React cannot pass objects into state'?

Comment: I came across an error with a console log from within react stating that the object must be parsed into an array.  Let me see if i can replicate that error